# Is it possible to use jQAssistant as a tool inside a java application?

Tags: java, jqassistant

I am currently working on a small project. The idea is to use jQAssistant to fill the neo4j database so that the data can be used by an rest api. The plan is to upload a jar, war or ear to a java backend so that it can be scanned (scan -f) and then start the neo4j server on port 7474.

**What I already have tried:**

**1.** Trying to execute "scan" and "server" with Java ProcessBuilder and Runtime.

**2.** Importing JQAssistant Commandline Neo4jv3 - 1.6.0 with gradle and trying to use the run-Method in Main.class with the commandline arguments (scan -f foldername).

Server-start works without any problems in both cases, but scanning is a huge problem. It does not seem to scan the specified folder correctly. The jqassistant-folder which has been created does not have any scanned data.

---

I assume that the root of the problem is the plugins folder and the variables JQASSISTANT_HOME and JQASSISTANT_OPTS appearing in the jqassistant.cmd and .sh files.

*Is it actually possible to execute "server" and especially "scan" within java code?*

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use jQAssistant from Java code but I'd not recommend it as the underlying APIs are subject to change. What remains downwards compatible over releases are the command line arguments, so going for the Main class as described in your question should be safe for a while. This approach is also used by the Gradle integration provided by Kontext E (http://techblog.kontext-e.de/jqassistant-with-gradle/).

Assuming that you're encountering the same problem with missing data when using the provided shell scripts for Windows/Linux. A common issue is that for scanning folders containing Java classes you need to specify a scope:

```
scan -f java:classpath::build/classes/main
```

The `java:classpath` prefix provides a hint that the folder shall be treated as a classpath element, see http://buschmais.github.io/jqassistant/doc/1.6.0/#_scanner and http://buschmais.github.io/jqassistant/doc/1.6.0/#cli:scan.